# cscope find the exact struct definition in linux kernel

Tags: cscope

I use cscope in vim. I want to find the definition of *struct platform_device*. I try

```
: cs find g platform_device
```

But the result contains lots of other things. like:

1. variable named platform_device
2. declaration of struct platform_device

   1    122  /work/pi/pi3_dev/linux-4.14/drivers/ata/pata_legacy.c <>
            int (*setup)(struct platform_device *, struct legacy_probe *probe,

   12     17  /work/pi/pi3_dev/linux-4.14/drivers/net/ethernet/qualcomm/emac/emac-sgmii.h <>
            struct platform_device;

the definition is also included in the result, but it't very difficult to find it because the output is too long.

Can it let cscope find only the exact definition of struct platform_device